Motion Blur makes smoke significatively more opaque
I have a smoke simulation already baked. When I try to render the image without motion blur, it renders normally, but when I enable motion blur, the whole scene turn into smoke.
I tried everything, but I could not find a solution.
Without motion blur:

With motion blur:

Domain options:



Could you please [edit] your question to change your domain options' screenshots so to only include what's actually needed? As it is right now, the only relevant areas of your screenshots are a small tiny corner of the whole area that we can't read without opening the pictures in a new tab to zoom in. It's always better not rely on your readers having to do extra steps to read you before even being able to help you ;)

Which render engine are you using? Also the render looks like there are other smoke simulations that are seemingly fine? If so, have you compared settings across their domains and emitters?
